# Why does ufw allow from all when told to allow from single IP

Tags: iptables, ufw

I am trying to connects a Web Server to a Media Server and so on the Media Server I want to open ports 1935, 1936 and 5080 to the Webservers specific IP address.

Using the following UFW commands I opened/allowed the ports to the IP address of the webserver.

```
sudo ufw allow from 127.154.145.29 to any port 5080
sudo ufw allow from 127.154.145.29 to any port 1935
sudo ufw allow from 127.154.145.29 to any port 1936
```

The problem is that these commands open the ports for ALL IPs because it creates another rule. After running those commands, this is what "sudo ufw status" shows:

My current firewall status is:

```
1935                       ALLOW       Anywhere
1936                       ALLOW       Anywhere
5080                       ALLOW       Anywhere
5080                       ALLOW       127.154.145.29
1935                       ALLOW       127.154.145.29
1936                       ALLOW       127.154.145.29
1935 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
1936 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
5080 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

On the Media Server when I run nmap 127.0.0.1 I get

```
root:~$ nmap 127.0.0.1

PORT     STATE SERVICE
25/tcp   open  smtp
1935/tcp open  rtmp
5080/tcp open  onscreen
9999/tcp open  abyss
```

Or nmap followed by the IP of the media server I get:

```
root:~$ nmap 131.245.111.219

PORT   STATE SERVICE
80/tcp open  http
```

If I use the command "sudo ufw deny 5080 1935 or 1936" the ports are closed and the Web Server isnt able to connect.

Can you see what I am missing here?

Thanks for any help you can offer.

PS: Of course this is also reflected in the IP tables

```
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:1935
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:1935
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:1936
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:1936
ACCEPT     ​tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:5080
ACCEPT     ​udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:5080
ACCEPT     tcp  --  29.ip-127-154-145.eu  anywhere             tcp dpt:5080
ACCEPT     udp  --  29.ip-127-154-145.eu  anywhere             udp dpt:5080
ACCEPT     tcp  --  29.ip-127-154-145.eu  anywhere             tcp dpt:1935
ACCEPT     udp  --  29.ip-127-154-145.eu  anywhere             udp dpt:1935
ACCEPT     tcp  --  29.ip-127-154-145.eu  anywhere             tcp dpt:1936
ACCEPT     udp  --  29.ip-127-154-145.eu  anywhere             udp dpt:1936
```

### ADDITIONAL INFORMATION BASED ON THE 2 RESPONSES BELOW

I have gone through the tips above and now the ufw status is:

```
5080                       ALLOW IN    127.154.145.29
1935                       ALLOW IN    127.154.145.29
1936                       ALLOW IN    127.154.145.29
```

The Iptables references are:

```
Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  127.154.145.29        0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5080
ACCEPT     udp  --  127.154.145.29        0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:5080
ACCEPT     tcp  --  127.154.145.29        0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:1935
ACCEPT     udp  --  127.154.145.29        0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:1935
ACCEPT     tcp  --  127.154.145.29        0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:1936
ACCEPT     udp  --  127.154.145.29        0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:1936
```

But the connection from the 127.154.145.29 websever still cannot be made.

I am presuming that the destination is ANY on the media server itself?

The only port open on the webserver itself is 80, but when I open  5080, 1935 and 1936 on the webserver that makes no difference.

Regarding what mook 765 stated above I have tried adding the IP address instead of ANY but that doesnt work. But I found out that ANY is the protocol and not an IP spot.

Any other suggestions apprecitated to help me solve this issue.

Many thanks

Comment: `sudo ufw allow from 127.154.145.29 to any port 5080` You explicitly allow to connect to any IP-adress, only the port-number is specified. Instead of `any` use the IP-adress you want to allow.

Comment: From `man ufw`: *"Rule ordering is important and the first  match  wins."* - based on your firewall status, you are allowing from anywhere to ports 1935, 1936, 5080 **before** trying to restrict to 127.154.145.29

Comment: Ah OK mook765 I'll take another look. But haven't I already stated I want to Only Allow 127. etc IP address. Why should I have to replace ANY with the IP again? Im kinda asking should I? as its already within othe command or are you meaning the External IP of the server whos ports 5080+ I am trying to open?

Comment: steeldriver the ports to open ANYWHERE are only added after I add the commands. I didnt add them. I will start again with this in the morning and delete everything and try again after I have worked out which command I actually need